# Rename tag: [amend] -> [git-commit-amend]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Most Git tags are named as git-something. This one is not.

Current tag: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amend/info
Suggested name: git-commit-amend

You may also review my tag wiki edit while you're doing it. :-) Though it may already be reviewed.

Tag has 80 questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now done. I've arbitrarily decided that the primary tag should be [git-amend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-amend), just because it's shorter than [git-commit-amend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commit-amend). (Note that there is already a [git-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commit) tag.) If you think that is a horribly wrong decision and can make a persuasive argument as to why, please do so in the comments below.

For the questions that were using the [amend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amend) tag but weren't about Git:

- The questions using the tag incorrectly (e.g., to refer to *amend*ing the text in some file or string) were simply retagged.
- Several questions were *correctly* using the [amend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amend) tag, but were about Mercurial instead of Git. For those questions, I've created the analogous [mercurial-amend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercurial-amend) tag.
- One question was about a Platform-as-a-Service solution called ["Amend Cloud"](http://amendcloud.com/docs/architecture_and_concepts); for that one, I created a [amend-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amend-cloud) tag for disambiguation. It doesn't seem like questions about that service are all that popular on Stack Overflow, but that may be because there wasn't a good tag for them, or it may be because the service is relatively new. Either way, I see no harm in creating a tag for these, even if it is rarely used.

Note that there is no longer a [amend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amend) tag in the system. This is by-design: a tag with this generic of a name would be readily subject to misuse.